# Android performance getJSONObject while parsing

Tags: android, json, performance, parsing, overhead

I'm currently parsing JSON and got the following piece of code:

```
boolean suf = list.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("sufficient");
String grade = list.getJSONObject(i).getString("grade");
String id= list.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
```

I'm wondering if multiple times calling getJSONObject creates overhead resulting in increasing processing time.

Would this be faster and/or better for example?

```
JSONObject object = list.getJSONObject(i);
boolean suf = object.getBoolean("sufficient");
String grade = object).getString("grade");
String id= object.getString("id");
```

This does introduce a new object, but will the next 3 calls make the tradeoff worth it?

Since I'm showing a dialog to inform the user something is loading (and thus they can't undertake any action), I'd like to minimize the wait time for the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd option is how I usually do. But you will hardly see any notice in performance. 
list.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("sufficient"); creates a temporary object and gets the value. Now a days, compilers are smart enough to store that temporary objects just in case them. Even if they don't, unless you are handling some millions of jsonobjs in your "list", I don't see any performance impact here.